# WPF Datepicker making only a list of dates selectable

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, datepicker

I'm not sure if this is possible but is it possible to make only a list of dates selectable in a wpf datepicker?

I need to make sure that the use can only select from a certain amount of dates. I can do this with a dropdownlist, but with a datepicker it would be much nicer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `DatePicker` has the following properties to control which dates should be selectable:

[DisplayDateStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.displaydatestart%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) : The first date to include in the `Calendar` popup.
[DisplayDateEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.displaydateend%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) : The last date to include in the `Calendar` popup.

So if you have a list containing allowed dates, you can set `DisplayDateStart` to the first item in the list, and `DisplayDateEnd` to the last item in the list.

That would prevent users from selecting dates outside that range.

To handle cases where the list of allowed dates contains gaps, you can use the `BlackoutDates` property to make ranges of dates not selectable.

So to add the dates that are not present in the list as blacked out, you can do something like the following.

Only the dates within the list are shown in the calendar popup, and the dates not in the list are blacked out so they can't be selected.

```
var dates = new List<DateTime>
{
    new DateTime(2013, 1, 5),
    new DateTime(2013, 1, 6),
    new DateTime(2013, 1, 7),
    new DateTime(2013, 1, 8),
    new DateTime(2013, 1, 15),
    new DateTime(2013, 1, 16),
    new DateTime(2013, 1, 28),
    new DateTime(2013, 1, 29),
    new DateTime(2013, 2, 9),
    new DateTime(2013, 2, 12),
    new DateTime(2013, 2, 13),
    new DateTime(2013, 2, 17),
    new DateTime(2013, 2, 18)
};

var firstDate = dates.First();
var lastDate = dates.Last();
var dateCounter = firstDate;

foreach (var d in dates.Skip(1))
{
    if (d.AddDays(-1).Date != dateCounter.Date)
    {
        dtp.BlackoutDates.Add(
            new CalendarDateRange(dateCounter.AddDays(1), d.AddDays(-1)));
    }

    dateCounter = d;
}

dtp.DisplayDateStart = firstDate;
dtp.DisplayDateEnd = lastDate;
```

If the allowed dates are very far apart, this would probably not be very user friendly, since it would be pretty annoying to have 90% of the dates blacked out. In that case a `ComboBox` might be better.

Comment: The list of dates i get can contain gaps

Comment: @GertHermans I see. So all the gaps should be blacked out. See my update for a solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can do what you want using the `BlackoutDates` collection to prevent the user from selecting all the dates you want to avoid.

Code:

```
myDatePicker.BlackoutDates.Add(myCalendarDateRange);
```

XAML:

```
<DatePicker Name="myDatePicker">
    <DatePicker.BlackoutDates>
        <CalendarDateRange Start="02.20.2013" End="02.22.2013" />
    </DatePicker.BlackoutDates>
</DatePicker>
```

Comment: This looks very good. But I need to just make a few dates available (which are in a list and differ for the different users) I'll have to blackout almost all dates, maybe it's best if I just go for the combobox option.

Comment: @GertHermans It shouldn't be too hard to blackout a lot of dates. You have `BlackoutDates.AddDatesInPast()` for all past days, or you could simply add a `CalendarDateRange` with a `Start` date and no `End` date for setting all dates after the start date as blackout dates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own ControlTemplate. The easiest way is to take the default template (you can download it from below URL ) and change the parts you want.

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsamples#themes